# Convexity of Gaussian Q-function (monotone decreasing)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, hessian-matrix, non-convex-optimization, gaussian

I have a known convex function. If I take the Gaussian Q-function of this convex function would the resultant function also be convex?

Comment: Does my answer answer your question? II think it does.

Comment: Yes, thank you Sir it did answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not even true when the convex function is $x$.

$1-\Phi(x)$ is not convex when $x < 0$. This can easily be seen by looking at the 2nd derivative of $1-\Phi(x)$, which is $\frac{x}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{exp}(-x^2/2)$.